# How can I adjust test in html<button> tag? (or better idea for calendar app?)

Tags: css, reactjs, calendar

I am making calendar app like Google Calendar, Samsung Calendar, Notion, etc...
So, I make calendar with React.
And,I want to make schedule function(click a day, write schedule).
But google says, tag can't be used for click!
So I make dayCells with  tag.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Calendar/>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;



const Calendar = () => {
  return(
    <div className='wrapper'>

      <div className='header'>
        <MonthNum/>
      </div>

      <div className='calendar'>
        <ul className='weeks'>
          <li>Sun</li>
          <li>Mon</li>
          <li>Tue</li>
          <li>Wed</li>
          <li>Thu</li>
          <li>Fri</li>
          <li>Sat</li>
        </ul>
        <ul className='days'>
          <DayCell/>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

const MonthNum = () => {  // to get month Number

  const [monthNum, setMonthNum] = useState([])
  const month = new Date().getMonth() + 1
  useEffect(() => {setMonthNum(month)})
  return( 
    <div>
      {monthNum}
    </div>
  )
}

const DayCell =  () => {   // to make DayList


  // day = day of week (ex. Mon, Thu ...)
  // date = date (ex. 1, 2, 10 ...)
  

  const [daysList, setdaysList] = useState([])
  const date = new Date(2023, 10, 6)   // Currunt date
  const currYear = date.getFullYear() 
  const currMonth = date.getMonth() + 1  // +1 for

  const firstDayofCurrMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth , 1).getDay();  // 
  const lastDateofCurrMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth , 0).getDate();
  const lastDayofCurrMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, lastDateofCurrMonth).getDay();

  const lastDateofBeforeMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth - 1, 0).getDate();
  const lastDayofBeforeMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth - 1, 0).getDay();  // to make before CurrMonth days(ex. ...'29, 30, 31', 1...)

  const firstDayofAfterMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth , 1).getDay() // to make after CurrMonth days(ex. ...30, 31, '1, 2, 3'...)
  const firstDateofAfterMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth , 1).getDate()

  const getBeforeMonthDates = (lastDateofBeforeMonth, lastDayofBeforeMonth) => {
    let BeforeDates = new Array()
    for (let i = lastDayofBeforeMonth; i >= 0; i--) {  
      BeforeDates.unshift(lastDateofBeforeMonth) 

      lastDateofBeforeMonth--
    }
    return( BeforeDates )
  }

  const getCurrMonthDates = (lastDateofCurrMonth) => { 
    let CurrDates = new Array()
    for (let i = 1; i <= lastDateofCurrMonth; i++) {
      CurrDates.push(i)
    }
    return( CurrDates )
  }

  const getAfterMonthDates = ( firstDateofAfterMonth, firstDayofAfterMonth) => {
    let AfterDates = new Array()
    for (let i = firstDayofAfterMonth; i <= 6; i++) {
      AfterDates.push(firstDateofAfterMonth)

      firstDateofAfterMonth++
    }
    return (AfterDates)
  }

  const DatesCombine = (BeforeDates, CurrDates, AfterDates) => {
    const FullDates = BeforeDates.concat(CurrDates).concat(AfterDates)
    return( FullDates )
  }

  const BeforeDates = getBeforeMonthDates(lastDateofBeforeMonth, lastDayofBeforeMonth)
  const CurrDates = getCurrMonthDates(lastDateofCurrMonth)
  const AfterDates = getAfterMonthDates(firstDateofAfterMonth, firstDayofAfterMonth)

  const FullDates = DatesCombine(BeforeDates, CurrDates, AfterDates)

  console.log(BeforeDates) // for test
  console.log(CurrDates)
  console.log(AfterDates)
  console.log(FullDates)

  useEffect( () => {setdaysList(FullDates)}, [] )  


  const WOW = () => {  // for Click test
    alert("WOWWWWWW")
  }

  return(
    daysList.map((day, i) => {
      return(
        <button className='dayCell' onClick={() => WOW()}>
          <span className='dayText'>
            {day}
          </span>
        </button>
      )
    })
  )
}
```

App.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.weeks {
  border: 1px;  /*border for test */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: aqua;
}

.calendar ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.calendar li {
  width: calc(100% / 7) 
}


div .days {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

button.dayCell {
  /* background-color: #ffffff; */
  width: calc(100% / 7);
  height: 90px;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  vertical-align: text-top; // text moving Tried!!

}
```

[result page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWFgh.png)

[What I want(notion calendar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Glc.png)
[What I want (Samsung calendar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Txy.jpg)

In notion calender, dayCell can be clicked and date positioned at top of the square. And I want to do that, too.

What I tried..

1. I tried margin, but it can't be used because I want to add schedule in dayCell.
2. I tried vertical-align, but it not works

So, conclusion is...

1. How can I adjust text in  tag?
2. Is there better way to make calender form like image(notion, samsung)?

p.s. This is my first question in stackoverflow. So this maybe have bad part for question. So any feedback on this question would be appreciated!

Comment: a lot of repetitive code. write abstract functions that return a new date in the format you want which properly cuts down the code by 30-40%

Comment: Why not try to get a calendar app off of GitHub?